How do I get Application Emoji
Discord supports having Application Emoji, how can I use them in Discord.JS?
I have tried this:
const emoji = client.emojis.cache.get('EMOJI_ID');

but it only returns an undefined. I uploaded the emojis at Discord's Developer Portal https://discord.com/developers/applications/APP_ID/emojis

As of now, there really isn't a way to get application emojis since it's such a new feature. You'd probably have to wait for the next Discord.js update to come out. Also the client.emojis is actually BaseGuildEmojiManager meaning that it returns emojis from all the servers of the shard.
You could upload the emoji to a server and then use client.emojis.cache.get("EMOJI_ID") to access it, that really is the only way I can think of right now but it's most likely gonna be available pretty soon so look out for that.
